# Bootstrap layout issue when displaying images

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been facing this issue for a day or so. Basically I have this code

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 {% for post in posts %}

  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="...">
     <div class="caption">
     <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
     <p>{{ post.body|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
     <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 {% endfor %}
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have two columns next to each other with an image diplayed. At the moment the first line is alright 2 images are displayed properly but on the second line only one is display. There is no margin or padding which block two images to be displayed on each second row.

[Image for the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv4Bu.jpg)

Comment: How is this a Python question?  Seems to me like this is purely html/css...

Comment: Because after all it uses Python for the backend.

Comment: I use a car to get to work, but that doesn't mean I should talk to my mechanic about getting a new chair for my office...

Comment: If you cannot say anything related to the topic please do not waste my time. If you would like to waste yours do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start by using the dev tools of your browser to add a `min-height` to see if it is a problem with containers of varying height. Possibly this could be your CSS rule set:

```
.thumbnail {
    min-height: 350px; /*try to make the min-height the height of your tallest thumbnail*/
}
```

Even though your screenshot makes the images look about the same height, you could have this problem due to the varying heights of the containers.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, I've tried quite a lot of options using thedev tool. Non of them seems to do the job.

Comment: Also, if you could create a simplified codepen or jsfiddle that contains the problem, i'd be willing to check it out and diagnose...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding a `clearfix` after every two iterations( As you are dividing two columns `col-md-6` in each row).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for post in posts %}

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ post.body|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
   {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
</div>
```